# Why does my thumb generator only make 36 images then stops

Tags: php

I have a website for pictures and want to make thumbs to make the loading speed faster.

```
    <?php
    function make_thumb($image, $thumbPath){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        $width = imagesx($img);
        $height = imagesy($img);
        $new_width = 100;
        $new_height = floor($height *( 100 / $width));
        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
        $thumbimg = $thumbPath . basename($image);
        imagejpeg($tmp_img, $thumbimg);
        echo "$thumbimg<br>";
    }
    $directory = "$location";
    mkdir($location . "thumb/");
    $thumbdir = $location . "thumb/";
    $picfiles = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,gif,png,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($picfiles as $disimg) {
        make_thumb($disimg, $thumbdir);
    }
    ?>
```

This is the code I made after look though lots of searches of similar code.

Edit 1:
There are 262 jpg files in the directory. Also I don't want it to generate it every time I am just doing at until it works then I will make it check if it exists.

Edit 2: result from
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d

./0001Camp2016.jpg
./0002Camp2016.jpg
./0003Camp2016.jpg
./0004Camp2016.jpg
./0005Camp2016.jpg
./0006Camp2016.jpg
./0007Camp2016.jpg
./0008Camp2016.jpg
./0009Camp2016.jpg
./0010Camp2016.jpg
./0011Camp2016.jpg
./0012Camp2016.jpg
./0013Camp2016.jpg
./0014Camp2016.jpg
./0015Camp2016.jpg
./0016Camp2016.jpg
./0017Camp2016.jpg
./0018Camp2016.jpg
./0019Camp2016.jpg
./0020Camp2016.jpg
./0021Camp2016.jpg
./0022Camp2016.jpg
./0023Camp2016.jpg
./0024Camp2016.jpg
./0025Camp2016.jpg
./0248VCamp2015.jpg
./0249VCamp2015.jpg
./0250VCamp2015.jpg
./0251VCamp2015.jpg
./0252VCamp2015.jpg
./0253VCamp2015.jpg
./0254VCamp2015.jpg
./0255VCamp2015.jpg
./0256VCamp2015.jpg
./0257VCamp2015.jpg
./0258VCamp2015.jpg
./0259VCamp2015.jpg
./0260VCamp2015.jpg
./0261VCamp2015.jpg
./0262VCamp2015.jpg
./download.zip
./0231Camp2016.jpg
./0232Camp2016.jpg
./0233Camp2016.jpg
./0234Camp2016.jpg
./0235VCamp2015.jpg
./0236VCamp2015.jpg
./0237VCamp2015.jpg
./0238VCamp2015.jpg
./0239VCamp2015.jpg
./0240VCamp2015.jpg
./0241VCamp2015.jpg
./0242VCamp2015.jpg
./0243VCamp2015.jpg
./0244VCamp2015.jpg
./0245VCamp2015.jpg
./0246VCamp2015.jpg
./0214Camp2016.jpg
./0215Camp2016.jpg
./0216Camp2016.jpg
./0217Camp2016.jpg
./0218Camp2016.jpg
./0219Camp2016.jpg
./0220Camp2016.jpg
./0221Camp2016.jpg
./0222Camp2016.jpg
./0223Camp2016.jpg
./0224Camp2016.jpg
./0225Camp2016.jpg
./0226Camp2016.jpg
./0227Camp2016.jpg
./0228Camp2016.jpg
./0229Camp2016.jpg
./0026Camp2016.jpg
./0043Camp2016.jpg
./0060Camp2016.jpg
./0077Camp2016.jpg
./0094Camp2016.jpg
./0111Camp2016.jpg
./0128Camp2016.jpg
./0145Camp2016.jpg
./0162Camp2016.jpg
./0179Camp2016.jpg
./0196Camp2016.jpg
./0213Camp2016.jpg
./0230Camp2016.jpg
./0247VCamp2015.jpg
./0197Camp2016.jpg
./0198Camp2016.jpg
./0199Camp2016.jpg
./0200Camp2016.jpg
./0201Camp2016.jpg
./0202Camp2016.jpg
./0203Camp2016.jpg
./0204Camp2016.jpg
./0205Camp2016.jpg
./0206Camp2016.jpg
./0207Camp2016.jpg
./0208Camp2016.jpg
./0209Camp2016.jpg
./0210Camp2016.jpg
./0211Camp2016.jpg
./0212Camp2016.jpg
./0180Camp2016.jpg
./0181Camp2016.jpg
./0182Camp2016.jpg
./0183Camp2016.jpg
./0184Camp2016.jpg
./0185Camp2016.jpg
./0186Camp2016.jpg
./0187Camp2016.jpg
./0188Camp2016.jpg
./0189Camp2016.jpg
./0190Camp2016.jpg
./0191Camp2016.jpg
./0192Camp2016.jpg
./0193Camp2016.jpg
./0194Camp2016.jpg
./0195Camp2016.jpg
./0163Camp2016.jpg
./0164Camp2016.jpg
./0165Camp2016.jpg
./0166Camp2016.jpg
./0167Camp2016.jpg
./0168Camp2016.jpg
./0169Camp2016.jpg
./0170Camp2016.jpg
./0171Camp2016.jpg
./0172Camp2016.jpg
./0173Camp2016.jpg
./0174Camp2016.jpg
./0175Camp2016.jpg
./0176Camp2016.jpg
./0177Camp2016.jpg
./0178Camp2016.jpg
./0146Camp2016.jpg
./0147Camp2016.jpg
./0148Camp2016.jpg
./0149Camp2016.jpg
./0150Camp2016.jpg
./0151Camp2016.jpg
./0152Camp2016.jpg
./0153Camp2016.jpg
./0154Camp2016.jpg
./0155Camp2016.jpg
./0156Camp2016.jpg
./0157Camp2016.jpg
./0158Camp2016.jpg
./0159Camp2016.jpg
./0160Camp2016.jpg
./0161Camp2016.jpg
./0129Camp2016.jpg
./0130Camp2016.jpg
./0131Camp2016.jpg
./0132Camp2016.jpg
./0133Camp2016.jpg
./0134Camp2016.jpg
./0135Camp2016.jpg
./0136Camp2016.jpg
./0137Camp2016.jpg
./0138Camp2016.jpg
./0139Camp2016.jpg
./0140Camp2016.jpg
./0141Camp2016.jpg
./0142Camp2016.jpg
./0143Camp2016.jpg
./0144Camp2016.jpg
./0112Camp2016.jpg
./0113Camp2016.jpg
./0114Camp2016.jpg
./0115Camp2016.jpg
./0116Camp2016.jpg
./0117Camp2016.jpg
./0118Camp2016.jpg
./0119Camp2016.jpg
./0120Camp2016.jpg
./0121Camp2016.jpg
./0122Camp2016.jpg
./0123Camp2016.jpg
./0124Camp2016.jpg
./0125Camp2016.jpg
./0126Camp2016.jpg
./0127Camp2016.jpg
./0095Camp2016.jpg
./0096Camp2016.jpg
./0097Camp2016.jpg
./0098Camp2016.jpg
./0099Camp2016.jpg
./0100Camp2016.jpg
./0101Camp2016.jpg
./0102Camp2016.jpg
./0103Camp2016.jpg
./0104Camp2016.jpg
./0105Camp2016.jpg
./0106Camp2016.jpg
./0107Camp2016.jpg
./0108Camp2016.jpg
./0109Camp2016.jpg
./0110Camp2016.jpg
./0078Camp2016.jpg
./0079Camp2016.jpg
./0080Camp2016.jpg
./0081Camp2016.jpg
./0082Camp2016.jpg
./0083Camp2016.jpg
./0084Camp2016.jpg
./0085Camp2016.jpg
./0086Camp2016.jpg
./0087Camp2016.jpg
./0088Camp2016.jpg
./0089Camp2016.jpg
./0090Camp2016.jpg
./0091Camp2016.jpg
./0092Camp2016.jpg
./0093Camp2016.jpg
./0061Camp2016.jpg
./0062Camp2016.jpg
./0063Camp2016.jpg
./0064Camp2016.jpg
./0065Camp2016.jpg
./0066Camp2016.jpg
./0067Camp2016.jpg
./0068Camp2016.jpg
./0069Camp2016.jpg
./0070Camp2016.jpg
./0071Camp2016.jpg
./0072Camp2016.jpg
./0073Camp2016.jpg
./0074Camp2016.jpg
./0075Camp2016.jpg
./0076Camp2016.jpg
./0044Camp2016.jpg
./0045Camp2016.jpg
./0046Camp2016.jpg
./0047Camp2016.jpg
./0048Camp2016.jpg
./0049Camp2016.jpg
./0050Camp2016.jpg
./0051Camp2016.jpg
./0052Camp2016.jpg
./0053Camp2016.jpg
./0054Camp2016.jpg
./0055Camp2016.jpg
./0056Camp2016.jpg
./0057Camp2016.jpg
./0058Camp2016.jpg
./0059Camp2016.jpg
./0027Camp2016.jpg
./0028Camp2016.jpg
./0029Camp2016.jpg
./0030Camp2016.jpg
./0031Camp2016.jpg
./0032Camp2016.jpg
./0033Camp2016.jpg
./0034Camp2016.jpg
./0035Camp2016.jpg
./0036Camp2016.jpg
./0037Camp2016.jpg
./0038Camp2016.jpg
./0039Camp2016.jpg
./0040Camp2016.jpg
./0041Camp2016.jpg
./0042Camp2016.jpg

Comment: Do you only have a total of 36 `.jpg`, `.gif` and `.png` images in `$location`?

Comment: Is your code creating a new thumbnail image for the entire directory on *every* page-load? If so, that's very inefficient - you should generate them once and then save them so they can be served as static files.

Comment: How many image files are in your directory referenced by `$picfiles`?

Comment: maybe .JPEG is to be included? I'd suggest to `glob($directory . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);` and then do `preg_match`

Comment: there are 262 image files in the directory

Comment: Can you execute the following in the dir where the images are and edit your post with the result? `find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d`

Comment: @roundtheworld execute it with what?

Comment: Shell or terminal.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am running ubuntu 16.04 @roundtheworld

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting enabled? Did you examine the error log? This could be a situation where you are exceeding `max_execution_time`.  or `memory_limit`.

Comment: It is enabled and where is the error log I did not get any errors on the page.

Comment: Using Ubuntu, open the terminal, `cd` to that directory, and execute the command I mentioned above.

Comment: there it is @roundtheworld

Comment: In your for loop, add the following as the first line in the loop `echo sizeof($picfiles) . " " . $disimg;` and tell me what it says.  Edit: changed `sizeOf` to `sizeof`.

Comment: i change in the php.ini file max_execution_time to 0 and it made 72 thumbs. How do i stop it from timing out. @roundtheworld

Comment: each image is about 2.1 mb in size.

Comment: If the problem is that your script runs slow and increasing the execution time is giving better results, the best solution is probably to architect a different approach.

Comment: I think you are right @MichaelBerkowski how to i fix that

Comment: Do you have evidence in your error log that the script is dying? You'll need to modify php.ini to increase `memory_limit` or set `max_execution_time` to zero. Actually, if you only need them changed for this script, place at the top of your script `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` or `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')` depending on how your code is actually failing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have evidence in your error log that the script is dying? You'll need to modify php.ini to increase memory_limit or set max_execution_time to zero. Actually, if you only need them changed for this script, place at the top of your script ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); or ini_set('memory_limit', '256M') depending on how your code is actually failing.